# Image URL not working as expected after being drawn in canvas in vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, canvas, vuejs3

I'm trying to crop an image that is being returned on request along with coordinations to crop the image at the specified position using *ctx.drawImage()* function, the drawn image is being shown on the DOM but when I try to get the dateURL of the canvas I get a base64 image back which is empty and doesn't contain the drawn image.

this is the code of the component that returns the canvas and the img I'm trying to show from the dataURL of the canvas.

```
<template>
    <canvas ref="canvas" :style="{ width }"></canvas>
    <img alt="canvas image" :src="imageURL" :style="{ width }" />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

const props = withDefaults(
    defineProps<{
        imageSrc: string;
        coordinates: string;
        width: string;
    }>(),
    {
        width: '120px'
    }
);

const imageURL = ref<string>('');
const canvas = ref<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);

onMounted(() => {
    if (!canvas.value) return;

    const ctx = canvas.value.getContext('2d');
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = props.imageSrc;

    img.onload = function () {
        const [x1, y1, x2, y2] = props.coordinates.split(',').map(Number);
        canvas.value ? (canvas.value.width = x2 - x1) : '';
        canvas.value ? (canvas.value.height = y2 - y1) : '';
        ctx?.drawImage(img, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1, 0, 0, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
    };

    imageURL.value = canvas.value.toDataURL();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export const createImageSrcCanvas = ({ elementId }: { elementId: string }): string => {
  const canvas = document.getElementById(elementId)
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
  context?.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  return canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
}
```

Comment: this is what i'm basically doing but out of a function

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your `toDataURL()` in the `img.onload` callback, not after. Doing `img.onload = function() ...` only registers the callback but the callback isn't called yet, hence an initial empty canvas:

```js
img.onload = function () {
    const [x1, y1, x2, y2] = props.coordinates.split(',').map(Number);
    canvas.value ? (canvas.value.width = x2 - x1) : '';
    canvas.value ? (canvas.value.height = y2 - y1) : '';
    ctx?.drawImage(img, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1, 0, 0, x2 - x1, y2 - y1;
    imageURL.value = canvas.value.toDataURL());
};
```

Comment: I have tried this before but it gives me the following error in the browser, I'm using firefox.

`Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure.`


And in chrome browser it gives me this error

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`

Comment: @ShakarKosar I see. A quick web search containing that message will point you in the right direction.

Comment: I searched for it previously, found issues like that but the solution was already implemented in my side which included browser settings manipulation but that is not an optimal solution even if it helps fix my issue in development it will still cause problems in production.
but thank you anyway for dedicating your time!
I do appreciate it.

Comment: @ShakarKosar Have you tried setting `img.crossOrigin = '*';`?

Comment: yes i tried this too, it gives me CORS error.